# JQuery & Html: How to wrap DIVs dynamically with another in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml

I have an `xml` file like this:

```
<posts>
    <post id="123">
        <title>UN meets on North Korean missile launch - </title>
        <link>index2.htm</link>
    </post>
    <post id="124">
        <title>UN meets on North Korean missile launch - </title>
        <link>index2.htm</link>
    </post>
</posts>
```

I have a div in my `html` file with `id='contact'` and I want to extract data from my `xml` file to divs in my `html`, so I'll choose the `<post>` tags from `xml` and extract `<link>` tag from it and place every few of them in one line `<div class="line">` so when this `div`s width equals the page width, the `<div class="line">` will close, and remaining `<link>`s most append to a new `<div class="line">` that will be generated.

```
<div id="container">

<div id="top-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Website.com</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Abilities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ideas</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<!-- Content Will Goes Here! -->
</div>

<div id="bottom-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Branches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Publishs</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

I want to do this with `JQuery` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"posts.xml",
        dataType:"xml",
        success:function(xml){

            var line = '<div class="line"></div>';
            $(line).appendTo('#content');
            $(xml).find('post').each(function(index, element) {

                var postLink = $(element).find('link').text();
                var postFont = $(element).find('font').text();

                var Link = '';
                Link += '<div class="link '+postFont+'"><a href="'+postLink+'">';
                Link += $(element).find('title').text(); 
                Link += '</a></div>';

                var lastLine = $('.line')[$('.line').length-1];
                var lineHeightBefore = parseInt($(lastLine).css('height'));
                //alert(lineHeightBefore);
                    console.log(lineHeightBefore);
                $(Link).appendTo(lastLine);
                var lineHeightAfter = parseInt($(lastLine).css('height'));

                if(lineHeightAfter > lineHeightBefore){
                    $('.link').last().remove();
                    $(line).appendTo('#content');
                    lastLine = $('.line')[$('.line').length-1];
                    $(Link).appendTo(lastLine);
                }

            });

        }
    });
});
```

But It doesn't work well.
Please see and test my codes to find the problem
thanks

Comment: What exactly, does "doesn't work well" mean?

Comment: @j08691 It means that, I want to put 2 or more of `.link`s to one div to create them like a single line. but some times it wrap only one `.link` to new div

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put content into that DIV.

$("#content").html(-what ever you want here-);

ex.
$("#content").html("some stuff");